# Message queue with conditional processing?

Tags: asynchronous, message-queue, messaging, business-process-management

I'm implementing workflow engine, where a job request is received first and executed later by a pool of workers. Sounds like a typical message queue use case.

However, there are some restrictions for parallel processing. For example, it's not allowed to run concurrent jobs for the same customer. In other words, there must be some sort of consensus between workers.

I'm currently using database table with business identifiers, status flags, row locking and conditional queries to store and poll available jobs according to spec. It works, but using database for asynchronous processing feels counterintuitive. Does messaging systems support my requirements of conditional processing?

Answer (score 0):

As an author of a few workflow engines, I believe that the persistence component for maintaining state is essential. I cannot imagine a workflow engine that only uses queues.

Unless you are just doing it just for fun implementing your own is a weird idea. A fully featured workflow engine is an extremely complex piece of software comparable to a database. I would recommend looking into existing ones instead of building your own if it is for production use. You can start from my open source project [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) :). It is used by thousands of companies for mission-critical applications and can scale to almost any rate given enough DB capacity.

Comment: I'm doing it just to implement architecture team's weird idea. I would use your tool if I could ;)

Comment: Show it to your team and you might convince them that the idea is weird indeed :).